# Java printing Objects Lists service by type

Tags: java

I have `Java` printing service  and methods for printing lists of objects.

```
public static void print(List<DbMatch> matches){
    for(DbMatch m:matches){
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}

public static void printOdds(List<Odd> odds){
    for(Odd o:odds){
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Or exist way to use one method not different for each type e.g:

```
public static void printObjects(List<Object> objects,Type type){
    for(type o:objects)
        System.out.println(o); 
}


PrintingService.printObjects(odds,"Odd");
PrintingService.printObjects(matches,"DBmatch");
```

Comment: And... what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generic method like this.

```
public static <T> void print(List<T> list){
    for(T m : list){
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```